# Why different characteristic dimension for Biot Number and Fourier Number?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, heat-transfer, thermal-conduction

In unsteady heat conduction analysis,

Biot Number and Fourier Number are given as follows:

$$Bi=\frac{h L_c}{K}$$

$$Fo=\frac{\alpha t}{L_c^2}$$

where $L_c$ is the characteristic dimension or length

---

As written in the book I'm following, **for Bi** $$L_c= \frac{V}{A_s}$$ where $V$ is the volume and $A_s$ the surface area of heat convection

which respectively, for a plane wall of semithickness $L$, sphere and cylinder of radius $r_0$ turns out to be $L, r_0/3,r_0/2$

**For Fo** the characteristic dimensions are $L, r_0, r_0$ for plane wall, sphere and cylinder respectively.

i.e.

| problem | Bi | Fo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a plane wall of semithickness $L$ | L | L |
| sphere of radius $r_0$ | $r_0/3$ | $r_0$ |
| cylinder of radius $r_0$ | $r_0/2$ | $r_0$ |

---

Even though both numbers correspond to the same type of problem i.e. a plane wall, cylinder or sphere through which convection happens at the surface and conduction within, the book choses different characteristic dimensions. It never talks about why though.

Comment: First, what is the "characteristic" dimension?

Comment: It's not crystal clear in my mind what a characteristic dimension is, but here's what I understand at present, a characteristic dimension is some length associated with the system which affects the behavior / physics of the system the most.

Comment: @HarshitRajput Are you sure that the characteristic length Fourier number for the cylinder is $r_0$. I have a suspicition that it should be L

Comment: @NMech Yes I'm pretty sure - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisler_chart#:~:text=%5B5%5D-,Infinitely%20long%20cylinder,-%5Bedit%5D

Comment: Does the cylinder  have infringe length?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what is meant by infringe length, but it's just a normal cylinder, solid, intially at $T_i$ and then heated in a furnace say, at temperatur $T_\infty$, and one dimensional heat transfer is assumed.

Comment: @NMech I would mark your since deleted answer as being complete starting at the definition for Bi.

Comment: @HarshitRajput I meant to write infinite instead of infringe (I think it was the autocorrection on my mobile). :-)    If it is infinite then the conductance does not make sense along the length of the cylinder, but radially instead.

Comment: @NMech yes conduction takes place only along the radial direction

Answer (score 2):

There is no unique definition for characteristic length.
The characteristic number is a number which is related to both the
problem and the geometry. So the characteristic length can be defined as any number that returns *length units* e.g. the square root of the surface area, as the third root of the volume, as the volume-to-surface ratio, etc. At the end of the day, it all depends what on the problem
(So I treat most characteristic lengths as a magical numbers that allow to compare different geometries on the same problem -- in other words is a convenience metric, and as such it has its pitfalls.)

The **Biot number**  is defined as

$$Bi = \frac{\text{Conduction resistance within the body}}{\text{Convection resistance at the surface of the body})}$$

again for a plate of cross-section A and length $L_C$ (along the direction of heat convection, the number is derived as follows:

$$Bi = \frac{\frac{L_c}{k}}{\frac{1}{h}}= \frac{h}{k} L_C$$

In both cases the derivations deal with the conductive heat rate (or its resistance which is the inverse) but on the denominator have different quantities, namely:

- heat convective resistance which is related to a surface
- and heat capacity which is related to volume.

Hopefully the derivation above for the rectangular plate makes sense, also the cylinder and the sphere is quite easy to derive for the Biot number.

| problem | Convective Area | Volume | $\frac{V}{A}$ (Bi) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a plane wall of semithickness $L$ | A | $A\cdot L$ | L |
| sphere of radius $r_0$ | $4 \cdot \pi \cdot r_0^2$ | $\frac{4}{3} \cdot \pi \cdot r_0^3$ | $r_0/3$ |
| cylinder of radius $r_0$ | $2\pi r_0 L$ | $\pi r_0^2\cdot L$ | $r_0/2$ |

---

**So the Fourier number** can be thought of as a ratio of the heat rate that is conducted across L of a Body of Volume, over the rate at which heat is stored in a body of volume.

$$F_0=\frac{\color{blue}{\text{the rate at which heat is conducted across L of a Body of Volume } }}{\color{red}{\text{The rate at which heat is stored in a body of volume  }}}$$

For a plate the length of interest is along the direction heat convection, so assuming a cross-section $A$ and length $L_C$ along the direction of heat convection:

$$Fo=\frac{\color{blue}{\frac{k}{L_c} \cdot A \cdot \delta T}}{\color{red}{\frac{c_p \cdot \rho \cdot V \delta T}{t}}}  $$

$$Fo=\frac{\color{blue}{\frac{k}{L_c}}}{\color{red}{c_p \cdot \rho }} \cdot \frac{\color{blue}{ A }}{\color{red}{V}} \cdot t$$

$$Fo=\frac{\color{blue}{k} }{ \color{blue}{L_c} \cdot \color{red}{c_p \cdot \rho } }\cdot \frac{1}{L_C} \cdot t$$

$$Fo=\frac{k}{c_p\cdot \rho \cdot L_C^2}\cdot t  $$

$$Fo=\frac{α\cdot t}{L_C^2} $$

where:

- $a= \frac{k}{c_p\cdot \rho }$

The Fourier number in the case of the *sphere* and the *infinite length cylinder* is a bit different. It actually involves radial heat conduction, so in that case intuitively the representative length is the radius.

Comment: I observed something in my textbook, even for the same Biot number while checking the applicability of Lumped system analysis, the book used Lc as V/A and while using the heisler's charts it uses the Lc (for Biot number) as simply $r_o$ for cylinder and spheres. So the Lc = V/A for Biot Number is even not consistent

Comment: @HarshitRajput this is in line of what I was saying right at the beginning, i.e. that there is no one characteristic length. What you noticed in the book makes sense, because when you are comparing between similar geometries then $r_0/2$ or $r_0/3$ isn't really that much different (also I am not certain how the book plots are drawn so there may be an implicit assumption there). The use of characteristic lengths is more evident though when you are trying to compare different geometries eg. flat and sphere or cylinder and a straightforward comparison is not possible..